# React Native 'setState' does not exist?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native, form-submit, setstate

I'm trying to make a post using Axios so I can add a person to my dataBase. I keep getting the error that "Property 'setState' does not exist on the type 'PersonForm' (fileName)".

[image]

My code currently:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { PersonForCreate } from '../data/person';

import axios from "axios";

class PersonForm extends React.Component {
state = {
    patients: [],
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    nin: "",
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addPatient = this.addPatient.bind(this);
  }

  addPatient() {
    let patientAdd = {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      nin: this.state.nin,
    };

    axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/person`, patientAdd).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  }

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput 
                key="firstName"
                placeholder="First Namee"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value });
                  }}            
            />
            <TextInput 
                key="lastName"
                placeholder="Last Name"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ lastName: e.target.value });
                  }}              
            />  
            <TextInput 
                key="nin"
                placeholder="National Insurance Number"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ nin: e.target.value });
                  }}              
            />      
            <Button title="Submit" onPress={this.addPatient}></Button>                          
        </View>
    )
}
}

export default PersonForm;
```

Would be very much appreciated if someone knew how to fix this problem or how to do this correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the state should be inside the constructor, change it to this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addPatient = this.addPatient.bind(this);

   this.state = {
    patients: [],
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    nin: "",
  };
 }
```

Comment: If I put the state inside the constructor, how do I add the values to the "let patientAdd"?

Comment: @JensPanis the same way you did in addPatient, this will work

Comment: "Property firstname does not exist on type readonly<{}>" is the error I am currently getting for the 3 values in addPatient.

Comment: @JensPanis are you using TS?

Comment: I am using TS yes, School made that a requirement. Forgot to mention sorry.

Comment: @JensPanis add this to your class declaration `class PersonForm extends React.Component<{},any>{`